# Matlab gui files in a package?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, figure

I am trying to put some `.fig` and their corresponding `.m` files in package.

I have:

```
 +ui/mainWindow.fig
 +ui/mainWindow.m
```

But when I try to run `mainWindow.fig` Matlab prints an error from GUIDE:

```
  Error using feval
  Undefined function or variable mainWindow
```

The funny thing is that if i call with its fully qualified name:

```
 ui.mainWindow
```

the window appears normally (but all callbacks don't work anyway).

I have tried to `import ui.*`  before running it.

Please note that I want to do this as sort of `namespace`. I don't want to have my entire application in the global scope of Matlab.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example including the function call and relevant matlab files that allows reproduction of this problem?

Comment: Dennis, I am opening and saving a simple Blank GUI with the code automatically generated by Matlab (2012a)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Explanation**

The fundamental problem is that *MATLAB GUIDE* is unaware of packages.  Normally, it manages the callback names automatically, keeping the *.m* and *.fig* files synchronized, and everyone is happy.  When the figure is within a package, it fails to properly update the callbacks in the *.fig* properties - these still point to the unqualified name *mainWindow* rather than the correct *ui.mainWindow*.  Subsequently, all callbacks fail.

**Workarounds**

Two ways around this one:

- Export your figure: `Guide -> File -> Export`. Place this file within your *+ui* folder.  Open the file, and do a *find-replace* replacing all instances of *@(hObject,eventdata)mainWindow* with *@(hObject,eventdata)ui.mainWindow*.
- Alternatively, you can manually update the references directly within *GUIDE* itself, without exporting. For each button and element, `Right Click -> Property Inspector` then edit the 'Callback' field, replacing *mainWindow* with *ui.mainWindow*.

Personally, I prefer the first solution because you can replace all occurrences with a single *find-replace* command.

Comment: Also, it couldn't be better to do an import.ui * instead to find and replace everything? The problem is I have tried that and it doesnt' work

Comment: In Matlab, import needs to be called within each specific function (not just at the top of a file for example). So for import _ui.*_ to work, you would to call the import within the event handler need function, which is Matlab internal and not accessible to the user.  My personal recommendation, and the most 'Matlab-ish' way to handle this problem, is to give your GUI functions a sufficiently specific name such that naming collisions are unlikely.

Comment: I have assigned you the full bounty, I don't think anyone else will be adding a new answer.